# Stopping dhclient on non-existent eth0 interface

Tags: systemd, udev

My Ubuntu 18.04.3 system takes an extra 90 seconds to boot because it is trying to run dhclient on a non-existent interface "eth0". At the same time, DHCP has already run and succeeded within 1 second on the correct interface "ext0".

```
Jan 29 13:46:38 server systemd[1]: sys-subsystem-net-devices-eth0.device: Job sys-subsystem-net-devices-eth0.device/start timed out.
Jan 29 13:46:38 server systemd[1]: Timed out waiting for device sys-subsystem-net-devices-eth0.device.
Jan 29 13:46:38 server systemd[1]: Dependency failed for dhclient on eth0.
```

There is no eth0 because I rename all PCI network interfaces in udev. The reason for the renaming is to have persistent names, and they can't be eth0 because udev no longer does that correctly (eth0 "File exists") That is discussed [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1016485/systemd-udevd-service-ignoring-60-net-rules).

```
# PCI device 0x1969:0xe0a1 pci@0000:04:00.0 (Qualcomm/Atheros Killer E2400 GigE Controller)
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="d8:9e:f3:82:e8:ed", NAME="ext0"

# PCI device 0x10ec:0x8168 pci@0000:71:00.0 (RTL8111/8168/8411 PCIE GigE Controller)
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="00:e0:4c:15:9e:56", NAME="int0"

# PCI device 0x168c:0x0042 pci@0000:03:00.0 (Qualcomm/Atheros QCA9377 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter)
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="5c:ea:1d:8a:db:35", NAME="wlan0"
```

systemctl shows correct entries for these devices, but I can't find any systemd unit file related to eth0. Where is it picking that up from, and how can I disable it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally solved it. systemd dependencies were `multi-user.service` -> `dhclient@eth0.service` -> `sys-subsystem-net-devices-eth0.device`. I had to:

```
mv /etc/systemd/system/dhclient@.service /lib/systemd/system/
sudo systemctl disable dhclient@eth0.service
```

This removed `/etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/dhclient@eth0.service`. Now the system boots much faster. I am using the `/etc/network/interfaces` method of running DHCP and am not sure how the systemd dependency got there. The file I moved was not in any Ubuntu package.